Is $\langle x+y^3,x^3+y \rangle$ a radical ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?
Let $u=x+y^3, v=x^3+y$.
Question: Is it true that $I=\langle u,v \rangle$ is a radical ideal?
Of course, $I$ is not a maximal ideal, since its generators have more than one common zero; the common zeros include $(0,0), (-1,1), (1,-1)$, etc.
(Solutions to $x(x^8-1)=x^9-x=0, y(y^8-1)=y^9-y=0$).
In order to show that $I$ is radical, we must show that $w^n \in I$ but $w \notin I$, for some $w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, or that the quotient ring is reduced.
Both $u,v$ are irreducible polynomials, see this question, but here we have two generators not one.
Any help is welcome! Thank you

Maybe you can first show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x+y^3) \cong \mathbb{C}[y]$ and use the theorem of correspondence to find the reducedness of the quotient ring

Thank you for the hint.
